# Split command across lines

Tags: windows, shell, console, split, command

In Linux shell, one can split a command across several lines using `\`. For example:

```
cmd \
  arg1 \
  arg2
```

How can I do the same using Windows console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ^

```
command line 1^
 line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One can split on other common operators on unix

```
command line 1 &&
  line 2

command line 1 |
  line 2
```